# Trouble calling function in another class/file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, class, prepared-statement

I have a class called "Stock" in foo.php:

```
class Stock
{
    public static function productExists($productsId)
    {
        $connection = TestDb::getConnection();
        $query = $connection->prepare(self::SQL_GET_PRODUCT_BY_ID);
        $query->execute([':products_id' => $productsId]);
        $product = $query->fetchAll();
        if ($product === false) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }
        return (count($product) > 0);
    }
}
```

I am trying to call it from another php file in the same directory. The code is this:

```
<?php

require ('foo.php');
$myClass = new Stock();
$res = $myClass->productExists(1000);
echo $res
```

I get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /Users/totalnewb/Documents/workspace/company/company_BE_QA_Script.php on line 286
```

Line 286 is line 7 in the above example. I have value in the database for that table/column that should return a boolean of 1 as I read it. The static SQL query referred to is fine and the DB connectivity is fine. I cannot touch the code in the Stock class. I know this is basic stuff so I am a bit baffled.

My other question is how come I can't put an echo statement into productExists to see the actual prepared statement? When I add `echo $query;` after the execution it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: Looks like prepare is not returning the object you are expecting to call execute (PDOStatement?) and instead is returning false

Comment: Thank you. Actually, the problem is that I don't have the MySQL driver for this installation of PDO. I'm running on OSX (I guess the PHP folks have never heard of it). It's kind of sad that it is so hard to get PHP working on a Mac. This stuff is utterly trivial in Python and Java. Long story short this code is all fine so I will leave this post intact.